# how to load webapplication on server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have made a web application using Visual studio 2008. till now it was running on my local host..

Now i want to load it onto the server so that it can run on my company server.

How do i do that..??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual studio:

1. Under the Build menu, select Publish
2. In the publish dialog, select a location to publish your application to
   ex: \\server\c$\inetpub\wwwroot
3. Set your publish options. I reccomend using the "Only files needed to run this application" setting
4. Click the Publish button

You will have to mark your deployment directory as an application in IIS for IIS to run your code. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha2y9493.aspx) for details on how to do this.

Comment: i tried to look for the IIS server in administrative tools... but it is not showing.. i am using windows server 2003

Comment: thanks i got it... i had to actually install IIS from my server 2003 CD... Dont kno why it was not installed in the first palce itself..?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy it into the IIS directory on that server, usually c:\inetpub\wwwroot. Make sure you have asp.net installed.

Comment: is the IIS directory already present, or do i need to download it

Comment: No, it does not need to have visual studio. IIS can be enabled via the Add/Remove windows components in the Control Panel on the windows server machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use the project menu and copy it to a remote server (specifically the machine that will host this project, in addition a web server).  Or you can just go to the remote machine, add a new site and store the .aspx pages and all related images on the web servers inetpub\wwwroot folder.

Comment: is the IIS directory already present, or do i need to download it